# Eclipse Mars - Random Number explanation

Tags: java, eclipse, random, eclipse-mars

I am currently using Eclipse Mars. When I used the Random library, I came across the following dropdown menu -

[image]

**What are these percentages that are mentioned**? (Please point out any duplicates - couldn't find one!) Thanks !

Comment: This is Eclipse's auto complete functionality, and the percentages indicate how likely Eclipse thinks the given method call is what you want.  It has nothing to do with `Random`.

Comment: @dimo414 I am aware of the autocomplete feature - but the percentages - nothing to do with the method ?

Comment: The percentage is a heuristic Eclipse is computing for each method, given the surrounding context.

Comment: @dimo414 - Sounds good. Thanks !